# Drupal error on bottom : Not Found The requested URL / was not found on this server

Tags: apache, drupal, drupal-7, vhosts

My website works but i have this error on bottom.

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use      an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at Port 80
```

this is my vhost configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@xxxx.com
        ServerName xxx.net
        ServerAlias www.xxxx.net
        DocumentRoot /var/www/xxxx.net/
        <Directory /var/www/xxxx.net/>
                  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                  AllowOverride all
                  Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ServerSignature Off
        ErrorDocument 404 /var/www/xxxx.net/404.html
</VirtualHost>
```

My 404 page exist at this location /var/www/xxxx.net/404.html

Thx for you help !!!!

Answer (score 0):

This may be malware code trying to load content from another host. I recommend to check your website.

Comment: I prefer [this tool](http://revisium.com/aibo/) It has a large database and checks files from inside. On-line scanners are not so good.